# Несколько переменных через .html() jQuery

Tags: jquery

Как правильно сделать запись кода, чтобы значения обеих переменных заносилось в нужный тег через метод .html()?

```html
  var type = $('input[data-type]:checked').val();
  var basement = $('input[data-basement]:checked').val();
  $('#last__par_total').html(type);
  $('#last__par_total').html(basement);
```

Так как написано выше, крайняя переменная переписывает всё что было до этого

Comment: `html(type + basement)` или `html(type).append(basement)`

Comment: А как возможно эти переменные внести еще в тег <р> к примеру?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculate() {
  var type = $('input[data-type]').is(':checked').toString();
  var basement = $('input[data-basement]').is(':checked').toString();
  $('#last__par_total').html(type + basement);
  $('#first').html(type);
  $('#second').html(basement);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' data-type=''>
<input type='checkbox' data-basement=''>
<button onclick='calculate()'>Calculate</button>
<div id='last__par_total'></div>
<p id='first'></p>
<p id='second'></p>
```